# An algorithmic fairness / equal calibration lemma

Tags: conditional-probability, expected-value

I'm having trouble with the lemma and proof on page 7 on this paper.

> Mitchell, S., Potash, E., & Barocas, S. (2018). Prediction-Based Decisions and Fairness: A Catalogue of Choices, Assumptions, and Definitions. arXiv preprint arXiv:1811.07867.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.07867.pdf

It states

$$E(Y |E(Y |X, A), A) = E(Y |X, A)$$.

The authors use this lemma to argue that the "equal calibration" fairness criterion can be achieved even without knowledge of protected attributes, provided the features used in the prediction system are rich enough. (Equal calibration says that, for example, recidivism prediction should get the probability of recidivism correct for White people and for Black people. I have an opinion about this criterion's merit or lack thereof, and I'm sure you do too, but it's not relevant to my question.)

The proof is

> Let $g(X, A) \equiv E(Y |X, A)$. By the law of total expectation:
>   $$E(Y |g(X, A), A) = E[E[Y |g(X, A), A, X]|g(X, A), A] = g(X, A).$$

I have four questions, sufficiently related that I think they all belong here on the same post.

- If the Law of Total Expectation states $E[B] = E[ E[B | C]]$, then does $C$ align with $X$ and does $B$ align with $Y| g(X, A), A$?
- Does the Law of Total Expectation justify the first equality, the second, or both?
- If it doesn't justify the second inequality, then what does? I can see how $E[Y |g(X, A), A, X] = E[Y |A, X] = g$, but then this is still stuck inside another expectation.
- In their paper, $Y$ means the variable being predicted, $S$ means the prediction, $X$ means the covariates, and $A$ is a protected attribute such as race. But in stating the lemma, they say it holds for any three random variable $A$, $X$, and $Y$. In their real-world interpretation of the lemma, do their variable names match the rest of the paper? If yes, then why does S not appear, and what is the difference between $g$ and $S$?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, C and B align with those expressions.
- It justifies the first inequality.
- The second inequality can be justified by first noting $E[Y |g(X, A), A, X] = E[Y |A, X] = g$, which matches both the desired right hand side and the expression inside the middle formula (the dot in $E[\cdot|g(X, A), A]$). The remaining task is to explain why the extra stuff in the middle (everything but the dot) is redundant. The answer is that $E[Z|Z,W]=Z$, where $Z$ aligns with $g$ and $W$ with $A$.
- The variables in the lemma do line up with the rest of the paper. The predictor $S$ is an estimate of $g$, which is the underlying population trend.